# How to detect the user city efficiently?

Tags: php, location

This question may look as a duplicate one, but the existing questions did not resolve my need.

I have checked so many questions on this topic in Stackoverflow and in Google, but I couldn't find the efficient method. Almost in all the threads people have suggested this site http://www.hostip.info/ to detect the user location. And when I try to check that site, it said me "No clue about your location". And in some other sites, my city is determined based on my IP address and it is wrong.

But in google.com or bing.com, the sites determined my location exactly. How they do that? How can I get the visitor location (just the city is enough) exactly? And in some sites I saw the Google Chrome throws a question to me, "Allow this site to share your location". How they use this feature?

Comment: _“it said me "No location about your clue"”_ – Yoda coded that page then must have. // https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+geolocation+api

Comment: I guess this is HTML5 Geolocation API, check http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The answer is "BY IP ADDRESS OF MACHINE / GEO-LOCATION"

There is a plugin written in php for do such task very easily,

Step-1) Download plugin from [here.](http://www.geoplugin.com/_media/webservices/geoplugin.class.php.tgz?id=webservices%3aphp&cache=cache)

Step-2) Little code snippet

```
<?php
    require_once('geoplugin.class.php');
    $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
    $geoplugin->locate();

    echo "Geolocation results for {$geoplugin->ip}: <br />\n".
        "City: {$geoplugin->city} <br />\n".
        "Region: {$geoplugin->region} <br />\n".
        "Area Code: {$geoplugin->areaCode} <br />\n".
        "DMA Code: {$geoplugin->dmaCode} <br />\n".
        "Country Name: {$geoplugin->countryName} <br />\n".
        "Country Code: {$geoplugin->countryCode} <br />\n".
        "Longitude: {$geoplugin->longitude} <br />\n".
        "Latitude: {$geoplugin->latitude} <br />\n".
    "Currency Code: {$geoplugin->currencyCode} <br />\n".
    "Currency Symbol: {$geoplugin->currencySymbol} <br />\n".
    "Exchange Rate: {$geoplugin->currencyConverter} <br />\n";
?>
```

For more details check out plugin website : [click here.](http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php)

> NOTE : If you wanna do same thing by your way you need a data of IP
>   address locations. Then after you can find it.

Comment: I'm in London, using dynamic IP - and half the time it shows me in Manchester :)

Comment: @AleksG : That service provider must keep updated db ;) isn't it?

Comment: The problem is that I am with a very large ISP, which has a pool of dynamic addresses spanning multiple cities.  There is simply no way to identify the city from the IP address, because the same IP address may be randomly assigned to computers in different cities.

Comment: *mozilla.com/en-GB/firefox/geolocation* says that if you're on a desktop it just does an IP location lookup using Google Location Services. Even same in Google Chrome. Google Location Service maintains the data base of users location. When you share your location with any of this service your location is directly sent to this db and they update it if any changes required !

Comment: Well, I ** _never_ ** allow any sites to access my location - maybe that's the problem then :)

Answer (score 3):

**Easy and simple code to detect city o country i hope to help you**

```
    $geoplugin = unserialize( file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip=' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) );
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_countryCode']."</h1> <br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_countryName']."</h1> <br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_regionCode']."</h1> <br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_regionName']."</h1><br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_currencyCode']."</h1><br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_currencySymbol']."</h1><br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_currencySymbol_UTF8']."</h1><br>");
   echo ("<h1>".$geoplugin['geoplugin_currencyConverter']."</h1>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Excellent services:

1) http://ipinfo.io/123.123.123.123

2) http://ip-api.com/php/123.123.123.123

3) [detect country & city (PHP, GeoIP Maxmind)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642598/detect-country-city-php-with-maxmind-geoip)